# Additional classes for price based on price components

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Is it possible somehow to add classes related to price components to the price container div? So you would be able for example to style a price based on how it is changed by its components. I thought it would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could theme the price components to add your own classes via a theme override.

The base implementation is in commerce_price.module

Here's a tweak that includes the price component $name in the class:

e.g, in template.php

```
/**
 * Themes a price components table.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   Includes the 'components' array and original 'price' array.
 */
function MYTHEME_commerce_price_formatted_components($variables) {
  // Add the CSS styling to the table.
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_price') . '/theme/commerce_price.theme.css');

  // Build table rows out of the components.
  $rows = array();

  foreach ($variables['components'] as $name => $component) {
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array(
        array(
          'data' => $component['title'],
          'class' => array('component-title', $name),
        ),
        array(
          'data' => $component['formatted_price'],
          'class' => array('component-total', $name),
        ),
      ),
      'class' => array(drupal_html_class('component-type-' . $name)),
    );
  }

  return theme('table', array('rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('commerce-price-formatted-components'))));
}
```