# How to customize a field price in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I have a field price in my grid and want to customize it.

Below are 2 pictures that will explain the situation:

[image]

[image]

**My question**: How can I customize that field to looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: uncheck use field template, check customize field HTML then select span on the drop down, check the use css box and then type uc-price

Comment: i tried that before , but nothing happened

Comment: well if that didn't work, the only possible explanation is that there is a theme template .tpl.php file that is overriding your view or a hook in your template.php file. So check your drupal/sites/all/themes/MyThemeName/templates folder to see if there is any file related to your view's name. Also check your template.php file in drupal/sites/all/themes/MyThemeName/

Comment: Well actually the easiest way to check would be by changing your website theme to a default untouched Drupal theme and check if you can see the span uc-price.

Comment: Or another explanation is that your view is cached, so you just need to clear your cache to see the new changes.

Comment: i forget to tell you , i work with drupal commerce , and that fiel related to price in drupal commerce ! that will no change any thing ?

Comment: I haven't worked with drupal commerce, so I couldn't tell ya, but I suspect it wouldn't

Comment: In views under Format Grid | Settings click on settings and uncheck Add striping (odd/even), first/last row classes. That should atleast get ridoff your "even" markup.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to customize the price via either of these contributed modules that can be used in combination with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Drupal Commerce Extra Price Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters) (has a stable D7 version):

> This is an add-on module for [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) that provides additional options when displaying the formatted price in your store.

- [Commerce Price FlexyFormatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_flexyformatter) (DEV version only).

> ... adds more options to format your products price.

Another option is to try what is described in the (accepted) answer to the question about "[Additional classes for price based on price components](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63108/additional-classes-for-price-based-on-price-components)", which includes a `template.php` tweak and states:

> ... you could theme the price components to add your own classes via a theme override.